# How to set user's preferred language in localStorage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a website user's preferred language via localStorage. The default language of the site is English, but if the user selects Spanish from the language dropdown, then the userLanguage in localStorage should be set to "es". I am following this post: https://www.carlrippon.com/react-drop-down-data-binding/ for reference regarding the dropdown component.

My question is how to set localStorage to the user's selection in a ***functional component***.

I am familiar with how to start setting it up until this point:

```
const [userLanguage, setUserLanguage] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("userLanguage", )
})
```

My confusion is what to do with the 3rd line, after "userLanguage, "

The dropdown selector component is as follows:

```
const Languages = () => {
  const languages = [
    { value: "en", label: "EN" },
    { value: "es", label: "SP" },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <LanguagesContainer>
        <Select
          id="language-selector"
          instanceId="language-selector"
          inputId="language-selector"
          options={languages}
          defaultValue={languages[0]}
          className="language-selector"
          classNamePrefix="language-selector"
        />
      </LanguagesContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing this:

```
const [userLanguage, setUserLanguage] = useState();
   useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("userLanguage", userLanguage ? userLanguage : '')
    }, [userLanguage])
```

Comment: you can read more about localStorage in react here https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/localstorage-react/